# TestNG - dependsOnGroups fails

Tags: testng

Why does the below testng group test fails?  My testng version is 6.11

**Test:**

```
public class MyTest {


    @Test(groups = "first")
    public void firstTest() {
        System.out.println("Executing first");
    }

    @Test(groups = "second", dependsOnGroups= {"first"})
    public void secondTest() {
        System.out.println("Executing second");
    }

}
```

This works fine.

```
mvn -Dgroups=first test
```

It fails saying `depends on nonexistent group "first"`

```
mvn -Dgroups=second test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestNG is working as designed here. If you include a group and if that group has a dependency on another group, then you would need to include both the groups for TestNG to run your tests.

So in your case, you would need to include both `first` and `second` for TestNG to run your tests (because `second` can only be run based on the result of `first`).

You can specify them as

```
mvn clean test -Dgroups=first,second
```